# Find the general solution of first-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $$xy*dy/dx +4y^2 -1 = 0 $$    x>0

I know it is a Homogeneous equation

And I rewrite by $$y'= (1-4y^2)/xy$$

Let y=xv substitute then

I got $v+xv'= 1/x^2v -4v$

I got stuck here, I can not integrate both sides to get the relation between x and v

Please help

Comment: It is not homogenous

Comment: Bernoulli’s equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hint:*** Try to use separation of variables
Separate and then integrate 
$$\int\frac{y}{1-4y^2}dy=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Comment: i could not separate this, it confuses me

Comment: is it clear now

Comment: yeah i see thanks